# How to get 10K products sample data in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sample-data

I have downloaded Magento 2.2 with sample data.

So in sample data instance, there are only 2046 products. So I want 10K sample data products data.

how can I get this data?

Because I want to test my module on 10k products.

Anyone know about this solution?

Comment: Export all product, then change the SKU and url_key and import again. Do this process 4-5 times. You will get more then 10k product.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: please upvote and accept answer..if it's useful for you. So, other user will use this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this command for create sample data product :

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /(Magento root )/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/(Profile xml as per your need)medium.xml.
```

You can use **medium.xml** for that

For more product create [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html).

Comment: I think your code will work and thanks for answer. I thankful and upvote and accept answer for you.I will check it this command. Thanks @rohan

Comment: Happy coding :) @Niraj

Comment: How to uninstall/remove this data?

Answer (score 1):

For More Information

I faced error **mysql server has gone away** while importing sample data products command so fix the error ,go to following path  `xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini` and increase packet value

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 512M

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 512M
```

Then restart mysql and apache.

-Go to magento2 root directory through command line

if you want to **import 800 products**(I have applied below code in local xampp windows) use below code

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
```

if you want to **import 4000 products**(I have applied below code in local xampp windows) use below code

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/medium_msite.xml
```

if you want to **import 24000 products**(I have applied below code in local xampp windows) use below code

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/medium.xml
```

if you want to **import 300000 products**  use below code

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/large.xml
```

if you want to **import 600000 products**  use below code

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/extra_large.xml
```

**Note:** If you are applying on a server this command so it should disable cron.

Comment: Please view my profile, Network profile for contact information, including Skype ID and get in touch with me.

Comment: How to uninstall/remove this data?